# Styling sidebar entries on Google Map marker hover/click

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am creating a kind of store locator app using Google Maps and need *1* more thing before I am finished...I need my sidebar entries to change background color when the corresponding markers are hovered over and selected.

I have been looking over a lot of similar questions here on SO for the last two days, but I couldn't figure out how to append solutions to my own project. Here is my code (as well as the commented out lines I was trying to retro-fit):

```
// this variable will collect the html which will eventually be placed in the side_bar
var side_bar_html = "";
//var leafmerchant = document.getElementsByAttribute("merchant_listing");
//var leafer = document.getElementByTagName("merchant_listing");
var street = "";
var city = "";
var state = "";
var zip = "";
var phone = "";

// arrays to hold copies of the markers and html used by the side_bar
// because the function closure trick doesnt work there
var gmarkers = [];
//var iterator = 0;
var map = null;

function initialize() {
  // create the map
  // HYBRID This map type displays a transparent layer of major streets on satellite images.
  // ROADMAP This map type displays a normal street map.
  // SATELLITE This map type displays satellite images.
  // TERRAIN This map type displays maps with physical features such as terrain + vegetation.
  var myOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.366896, -71.080135),
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    navigationControl: true,
    zoom: 16,

    mapTypeControl: true, mapTypeControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT,
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
    },

    panControl: true, panControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
    },

    streetViewControl: true, streetViewControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
    },

    zoomControl: true, zoomControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT,
      style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
    },

    scaleControl: false, scaleControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM
    }
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("merchant-map"), myOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() { infowindow.close(); });

  // Add markers to the map // Set up markers with info windows // add the points
  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(42.366896, -71.080135);
  var marker = createMarker(point, "Leaf HQ", "Some stuff to display in the<br/>First Info Window", "222 Third Street", "Cambridge", "MA", "02142", "617-890-1234")

  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(42.363341, -71.079523);
  var marker = createMarker(point, "Casa B", "Some stuff to display in the<br/>First Info Window", "253 Washington Street", "Somerville", "MA", "02143", "617-764-2180")

  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(42.368996, -71.085831);
  var marker = createMarker(point, "Sepal", "Some stuff to display in the<br/>Third Info Window", "84 Massachusetts Avenue", "Cambridge", "MA", "02139", "617-324-5568")

  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(42.367111, -71.076822);
  var marker = createMarker(point, "Café Luna", "Some stuff to display in the<br/>Fourth Info Window", "403 Massachusetts Avenue", "Cambridge", "MA", "02139", "617-576-3400")

  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(42.367997, -71.081146);
  var marker = createMarker(point, "Leaf HQ", "Some stuff to display in the<br/>First Info Window", "222 Third Street", "Cambridge", "MA", "02142", "617-890-1234")

  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(42.364442, -71.078504);
  var marker = createMarker(point, "Casa B", "Some stuff to display in the<br/>First Info Window", "253 Washington Street", "Somerville", "MA", "02143", "617-764-2180")

  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(42.340097, -71.084842);
  var marker = createMarker(point, "Sepal", "Some stuff to display in the<br/>Third Info Window", "84 Massachusetts Avenue", "Cambridge", "MA", "02139", "617-324-5568")

  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(42.368212, -71.075803);
  var marker = createMarker(point, "Café Luna", "Some stuff to display in the<br/>Fourth Info Window", "403 Massachusetts Avenue", "Cambridge", "MA", "02139", "617-576-3400")

  // put the assembled side_bar_html contents into the side_bar div
  document.getElementById("merchant_list").innerHTML = side_bar_html;
}

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow ({ size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50) });

// This function picks up the click and opens the corresponding info window
function myclick(i) { google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click"); }

// A function to create the marker and set up the event window function
function createMarker (latlng, name, html, street, city, state, zip, phone) {
  //var contentString = html;
  var contentString = '<div id="content">' +
    '<span class="title">' + name + '<\/span>' +
    '<div class="infomap-address">' +
    '<div class="address-01">' + street + '<\/div>' +
    '<div class="address-02">' + city + ',&nbsp;' + state + '&nbsp;' + zip + '<\/div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="infomap-address">Get directions' +
    '<\/div>'
    '<\/div>';
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker ({
    //icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/green.png",
    map: map,
    position: latlng,
    zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5,
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });

  //google.maps.event.addListener(div, 'mouseover', function() { div.style.backgroundColor = '#eee'; });
  //google.maps.event.addListener(div, 'mouseout', function() { div.style.backgroundColor = '#fff'; });

  //google.maps.event.addListener(leafmerchant, 'mouseover', function() { leafmerchant.style.backgroundColor = '#eee'; });
  //google.maps.event.addListener(leafmerchant, 'mouseout', function() { leafmerchant.style.backgroundColor = '#fff'; });

  // save the info we need to use later for the side_bar // add a line to the side_bar html
  gmarkers.push(marker); side_bar_html += '<li class="merchant_listing vcard">'
  + '<a class="url fn org" href="javascript:myclick(' + (gmarkers.length-1) + ')">' + name + '<\/a><br/>'
  + '<div class="adr">'
  + '<div class="street-address">' + street + '<\/div>'
  + '<span class="locality">' + city + ',&nbsp;<\/span>'
  + '<span class="region">' + state + '&nbsp;<\/span>'
  + '<span class="postal-code">' + zip + '<br/><\/span>'
  + '<a class="tel">' + phone + '<\/a>'
  + '<\/div>'
  + '<\/li>';

  marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.DROP);
  //function drop(){ for (i =0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) { setTimeout(function() { addMarkerMethod();}, i * 200); }}

  //google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() { document.getElementByTagName(merchant_listing).style.backgroundColor = '#07d0eb'; });
  //google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() { document.getElementByTagName(merchant_listing).style.backgroundColor = '#191919'; });

  //google.maps.event.addListener(gmarkers, 'mouseover', function() { leafer.style.backgroundColor = '#eee'; });
  //google.maps.event.addListener(gmarkers, 'mouseout', function() { leafer.style.backgroundColor = '#fff'; });
}
```

Comment: Can you give a little more detail? What specifically isn't working after your set up your `google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'mouseover', function )` event listeners? Do you see evidence that the event listeners are getting called? It looks like you are on the right track, but if you can add detail it will be easier to give you some help.

Comment: I am not quite sure, to be honest. I also don't know how to check to see if the event listeners are getting called. I do know that when I uncomment the lines to allow for the sidebar highlighting, the sidebar items disappear and/or only the first marker appears on the map.